# SEO test tool doesn't see my H1 generated by JavaScript, will Google?

Tags: seo, googlebot, javascript, heading

On what basis is SEO checked? When I examine my page, an H1 tag is present. However, when I look at the page source, an H1 heading is not present because it is generated via JavaScript (CMS in the background). When I run an SEO checker over the page it tells me that an H1 heading is missing. So my question: does google check my page based on the source text or based on what a user sees at the end?

Comment: Google usually checks the source text when crawling a site. What is the URL that you are enquiring about so that I can have a look?

Comment: Is the `<h1>` in question based on a JS "event" (like onclick, onmouseover, etc.)?